# Rspec shoulda matcher test on activerecord model fails due to validation of associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, rspec

My model has a validation concerning one of it's associated models. My rspec tests of the model are failing due to this validation.

```
describe NewOfferRange do
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:new_offer) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:from) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:to) }
end

class NewOfferRange < ApplicationRecord
  validates :new_offer, :from, :to, presence: true
  validate :unique_for_date_ranges

  delegate :hotel, to: :new_offer

  def unique_for_date_ranges
    if hotel.new_offers.joins(:new_offer_ranges)
            .where('new_offer_ranges.from < ? AND new_offer_ranges.to > ?', to, from)
            .where.not(new_offer_ranges: { id: id })
            .count
            .positive?
      errors.add(:base, 'Ya hay otra oferta para esas fechas.')
  end
end
```

Those test fail because when trying to run the validation, it says `new_offer is nil` for the `new_offer_range`.

I'm also using FactoryGirl for my model factories which has defined a factory for `new_offer_range` that is valid and has the corresponding references.
Can I somehow tell should matchers to use that factory so as not to get this validation error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting

```
subject { create :new_offer_range }
```

before `it`-blocks should solve the problem. It will set the subject of testing, not a default object, but one that you want to have.

Comment: Thank you, just tried that before reading this answer and was about to post it.